# filter based media search with google photos API (python)

Tags: python, google-photos-api

I'm trying to use the `mediaItems().search()` method, using the following body:

```
body = {
        "pageToken": page_token if page_token != "" else "",
        "pageSize": 100,
        "filters": {
            "contentFilter": {
                "includedContentCategories": {"LANDSCAPES","CITYSCAPES"}
            }
        },
        "includeArchiveMedia": include_archive
    }
```

but the problem is that the set `{"LANDSCAPES","CITYSCAPES"}` should actually be a set of enums (as in Java enums), and not strings as ive written. this is specified in the API: (https://developers.google.com/photos/library/reference/rest/v1/albums)

> ContentFilter - This filter allows you to return media items based on the content type.
>
> JSON representation
>
> ```
> {
>   "includedContentCategories": [
>     enum (ContentCategory)
>   ],
>   "excludedContentCategories": [
>     enum (ContentCategory)
>   ]
> }
> ```

is there a proper way of solving this in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- When `albumId` and `filters` are used, an error of `The album ID cannot be set if filters are used.` occurs. So when you want to use `filters`, please remove `albumId`.
- The value of `includedContentCategories` is an array as follows.

  - `"includedContentCategories": ["LANDSCAPES","CITYSCAPES"]`
- `includeArchiveMedia` is `includeArchivedMedia`.
- Please include `includeArchivedMedia` in `filters`.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
body = {
    # "albumId": album_id,  # <--- removed
    "pageToken": page_token if page_token != "" else "",
    "pageSize": 100,
    "filters": {
        "contentFilter": {
            "includedContentCategories": ["LANDSCAPES", "CITYSCAPES"]
        },
        "includeArchivedMedia": include_archive
    }
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Method: mediaItems.search](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/reference/rest/v1/mediaItems/search)

Comment: @Hadar Sharvit Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.